# Adding a client application to Azure AD application is throwing error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a Azure AD app which has certain client applications already mapped to it. I now tried to add a new client application but it's throwing me the error -

> Failed to update 'XXXX' application. Error detail: The client ID
>   provided could not be found. [sGg8r]

I, then created another Azure AD application and repeated the above steps to add it as a client app but to no avail.

I have checked and verified many times that my client ID is correct and exists. What else could be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting if anyone faces this issue in the future.

I had a look at the previously mapped client applications. Some of them had been deleted earlier but these mappings persisted.Once I cleaned up the mapped client applications, I was able to add the client id of the newly created application.

TLDR; **Remove any of the client applications which are not searchable anymore and then add the new one.**